# Is this a scam? A web page claims my iPhone is infected

Tags: ipod, virus

[image]

Is this a scam? I do not use adult sites.

I think this is a scam because I'm using an iPod touch when it clearly states iPhone. Please answer truthfully for future experiences

Comment: Of course it's a scam... "appcommercialsfree.site" ...

Answer (score 6):

Yes. This is a scam. You are 100% safe to close your safari tab to get rid of this message and absolutely nothing will happen. Many scammers provide fake instructions which will tell you what to do to give them access to your device, or make you give them money or personal details too, without you realising.

In this case, due to the web address, it appears the only intention of this fake site is to get you to install an app, probably to make the app seem more popular. The address implies this is an advertisement of an app, and the bit we can see of the instructions seems to back this up too. It is possible they are still trying to get money if the app costs money.

Answer (score 0):

lol I receive the same as well on my iPhone and iPad, I even got one that had the BSOD (blue screen of death) for windows I was just laughing it was priceless on an Apple device, the message kept coming up so I ended in deleting the app and re-added and worked just fine.

Hope this all helps it was fun

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up for future reference - if they are telling you to do something which seems suspicious or unnecessary (eg. Downloading an app) its probably a scam. If the url does not seem right or is overly long, its probably a scam, and if the spelling is off and its got a huge red timer counting down, its probably a scam.